# Is there any way I can get a performance summary Results(Scripting, Rendering, Idle time)?

Tags: lighthouse

I want to capture chrome performance summary. Scripting, Rendering, Loading, Idle and Other time programatically. I want know is there any metrics lighhouse generates which I can use?.

I have tried https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf. It doesn't calculate Other and idle time. I looked at chromium source code (TimeLineUtil.js) to see if I can use the same logic to capture these details. It seems bit complex. Thought of asking this question here. If anyone already implemented the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for The Page Speed API: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#response. Or is that insufficient?

Comment: Thank you @JoostS. I did try to look up for the performance summary factors - Scripting, Rendering, Loading, Idle, Total time with this API. Looks like this API won't give that details.

Comment: @RahulM were you able to do that? Trying to do the same thing atm

Comment: Sorry Jonathan. It's been a while I did not login to StackOverflow. I was able to resolve somehow by using the devtools-timeline-model npm package.

const devtools = require("devtools-timeline-model");  
const start = timelineModel.timelineModel()._minimumRecordTime;
const end = timelineModel.timelineModel()._maximumRecordTime;
console.log('Total Time', end - start);
const tracingModel = timelineModel.tracingModel();
 if (summary.has(SCRIPTING)) { console.log(SCRIPTING, time(summary, SCRIPTING)); }

    function time(summary, type) {
        return summary.get(type).totalTime;
    }